# input texbox value not working in textbox javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, textbox

I would like to know how to allow max value based on min entered in textbox and should allow only numbers and no special characters and alphabets,

I have two text box, min and max,
`min` can allow only numbers both positive and negative but no special characters and alphabets

`max` value should be greater than min value and not allow special characters and alphabets

Here is my code, max not working proper.

```
class Sample extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      min: "",
      max: ""
    }
 }
hanldeMin = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value !== "") {
      this.setState({
        min: e.target.value
      })
    }
  }

 handleMax = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value !== "") {
      if (parseInt(e.target.value) < parseInt(this.state.min)) {
        e.target.value = "";
      }
      this.setState({
        max: e.target.value
      })
    }
  }
render(){
return (
 <React.Fragment>
   <div className="row">

       <div className="col-lg-5 col-sm-5 noPadding noMargin">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="min"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="minavlitems"
                  value={this.state.min}
                  onChange={(event) => {
                    if (isNaN(Number(event.target.value))) {
                      return;
                    } else {
                      this.hanldeMin(event);
                    }
                  }}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="col-lg-1 col-sm-1 alignCenter noPadding noMargin">
                <b>-</b>
              </div>
              <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 noPadding noMargin">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  min={this.state.min}
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="max"
                  id="maxavlitems"
                  value={this.state.max}
                  onChange={(event) => {
                    if (isNaN(Number(event.target.value))) {
                      return;
                    } else {
                       this.hanldeMax(event);
                    }
                  }}                 
                />
              </div>
             </div>
   </div>
 </React.Fragment>

)

}

}
```

Comment: why are you setting `e=""`?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the example where I used `regular expression` to input only positive/negative number.

[Here is the Code Sand Box](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-smoke-kwh83)

**Here is the example:**

```
import React from "react";

export default class Sample extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            min: "",
            max: ""
        }
    }

    isValid = (e) => {
        let regEx = /^-?\d*\.?\d{0,6}$/;
        let text = e.target.value;
        return (text.match(regEx) !== null);
    };

    handleMin = (e) => {
        if (this.isValid(e)) {
            this.setState({
                min: e.target.value
            })
        }
    };

    handleMax = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.value, 'onblur');
        if (this.isValid(e)) {
            if (parseInt(e.target.value) <= parseInt(this.state.min)) {
                e.target.value = "";
            }
            this.setState({
                max: e.target.value
            })
        }
    };

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            max: e.target.value
        })
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-lg-5 col-sm-5 noPadding noMargin">
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="min"
                            className="form-control"
                            id="minavlitems"
                            value={this.state.min}
                            onChange={this.handleMin}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-lg-1 col-sm-1 alignCenter noPadding noMargin">
                        <b>-</b>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 noPadding noMargin">
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            min={this.state.min}
                            className="form-control"
                            placeholder="max"
                            id="maxavlitems"
                            value={this.state.max}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            onBlur={this.handleMax}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <button onClick={() => {
                        console.log(this.state, 'state')
                    }}>Show mix and max value in console
                    </button>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, but when i enter min 10, max cannot enter value

Comment: Hi, I have updated my answer. now it is working. please check

Comment: same issue,cannot enter value in max

Comment: Please use code sand box link. It is perfectly working. also I added a picture for showing that I can enter value.

Comment: @kabir, but when i enter min 10, max should allow only > 10, but it allows

Comment: why you are not try code sandbox url? I put 10 in min and when I put 10 in max and change focus from max, 10 is removed from max for the validation and this is what you have asked. Again, please try url https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-smoke-kwh83

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the state even your `max` input is less than `min` in state.

Change your if condition as follows

```
handleMax = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value !== "") {
      if (parseInt(e.target.value) > parseInt(this.state.min))
         this.setState({
           max: e.target.value
         })
     }
  }
```